# How to return alphabetical substrings?

Tags: python, python-2.7, while-loop

I'm trying to write a function that takes a string `s` as an input and returns a list of those substrings within `s` that are alphabetical. For example, `s = 'acegibdh'` should return `['acegi', 'bdh']`.

Here's the code I've come up with:

```
s = 'acegibdh'
ans = []
subs = []
i = 0
while i != len(s) - 1:
    while s[i] < s[i+1]:
        subs.append(s[i])
        i += 1
    if s[i] > s[i-1]:
        subs.append(s[i])
        i += 1
    subs = ''.join(subs)
    ans.append(subs)
    subs = []
print ans
```

It keeps having trouble with the last letter of the string, because of the i+1 test going beyond the index range. I've spent a long time tinkering with it to try and come up with a way to avoid that problem. Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: Your requirement is unclear. If it cut all the substrings to length 1 and sorted them, it sounds like it fulfills the requirement. Can you be more specific about why that input should give that output and not a different one?

Comment: shouldn't your condition be `i < len(s) - 1` since `i` can be incremented twice inside the loop?

Comment: Try putting some examples of what your expected output for a given input .  question is unclear from 1 example

Comment: Sounds like he wants to split a string up into the smallest possible number of substrings, each of which is already in ascending alphabetical order. As another example, "abcxyzmdef" would become `['abcxyz', 'm', 'def']`.

Answer (score 4):

Why not hard-code the first letter into `ans`, and then just work with the rest of the string? You can just iterate over the string itself instead of using indices.

```
>>> s = 'acegibdh'
>>> ans = []
>>> ans.append(s[0])
>>> for letter in s[1:]:
...     if letter >= ans[-1][-1]:
...             ans[-1] += letter
...     else:
...             ans.append(letter)
...
>>> ans
['acegi', 'bdh']
```

Answer (score 1):

```
s = 'acegibdh'
ans = []
subs = []
subs.append(s[0])
for x in range(len(s)-1):
    if s[x] <= s[x+1]:
        subs.append(s[x+1])
    if s[x] > s[x+1]:
        subs = ''.join(subs)
        ans.append(subs)
        subs = []
        subs.append(s[x+1])
subs = ''.join(subs)
ans.append(subs)
print ans
```

I decided to change your code a bit let me know if you have any questions

Answer (score 1):

Just for fun, a one line solution.

```
>>> s='acegibdh'
>>> [s[l:r] for l,r in (lambda seq:zip(seq,seq[1:]))([0]+[idx+1 for idx in range(len(s)-1) if s[idx]>s[idx+1]]+[len(s)])]
['acegi', 'bdh']
```

Answer (score 0):

More than one while loop is overkill. I think this is simpler and satisfies your requirement. Note, this fails on empty string.

```
s = 'acegibdh'
ans = []
current = str(s[0])
i = 1
while i < len(s):
    if s[i] > s[i-1]:
        current += s[i]
    else: 
        ans.append(current)
        current = ''
    i += 1
if current != '':
   ans.append(current)
print ans
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try to avoid loops that increment the position by more than one char per iteration.

Often it is more clear to introduce an additional variable to store information about the previous state:

```
s = 'acegibdh'
prev = None
ans = []
subs = []
for ch in s:
    if prev is None or ch > prev:
        subs.append(ch)
    else:
        ans.append(''.join(subs))
        subs = [ch]
    prev = ch
ans.append(''.join(subs))
```

I think this read more straight forward (if there is no previous character or it's still alphabetical with the current char append, else start a new substring). Also you can't get index out of range problems with this approch.

Comment: This also is safe for an empty input. Gives `[ "" ]` as output in that case.

Answer (score 0):

just for fun cause I like doing things a little different sometimes

```
from itertools import groupby,chain,cycle

def my_gen(s):
    check = cycle([1,0])
    for k,v in groupby(zip(s,s[1:]),lambda x:x[0]<x[1]):
        if k:
            v = zip(*v)
            yield v[0] + (v[1][-1],)

print list(my_gen('acegibdhabcdefghijk'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Some of the solutions posted have an index error for empty strings.

Also, instead of keeping a list of characters, or doing repeated string concatenations, you can track the start index, `i`, of a solution substring and yield `s[i:j]` where `s[j] < s[j-1]`, then set `i` to `j`.

Generator that yields substrings when the next letter is lexicographically less than the previous:

```
def alpha_subs(s):
    i, j = 0, 1
    while j < len(s):
        if s[j] < s[j-1]:
            yield s[i:j]
            i = j
        j += 1
    if s[i:j]:
        yield s[i:j]
```

---

```
print(list(alpha_subs('')))
print(list(alpha_subs('acegibdh')))
print(list(alpha_subs('acegibdha')))
```

---

```
[]
['acegi', 'bdh']
['acegi', 'bdh', 'a']
```

For case insensitivity:

```
def alpha_subs(s, ignore_case=False):
    qs = s.lower() if ignore_case else s
    i, j = 0, 1
    while j < len(s):
        if qs[j] < qs[j-1]:
            yield s[i:j]
            i = j
        j += 1
    if s[i:j]:
        yield s[i:j]
```

---

```
print(list(alpha_subs('acEgibDh', True)))
print(list(alpha_subs('acEgibDh')))
```

---

```
['acEgi', 'bDh']
['ac', 'Egi', 'b', 'Dh']
```